# Mobile: Red banner reading option_id appears when flagging too fast

Tags: bug, android-app

I recently started using Stack Exchange on mobile, and found two questions really close to each other that needed flagged (unclear what you're asking and looking for software recommendations). When I flagged the second one, a red banner appeared that read `option_id`. I am assuming that this was from flagging too fast, because it worked normally a minute later. It appears to be a variable (perhaps undefined?) that should say something similar to "You are flagging too fast. Please wait (XX) seconds".